# WPF Toolkit Внешний вид Chart когда ItemsSource равно null

Tags: c#, wpf, диаграммы, wpf-toolkit

Проблема в следующем: когда в `Chart` еще нет данных он выглядит так
[image: Внешний вид при первом запуске]

Но потом, если нарисовать график и очистить его, то получится так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

XAML Chart

```
        <!--Chart column-->
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="12"
                           Margin="5"
                           Padding="0"
                           Name="chartColumn"
                           Visibility="{Binding ColumnSeriesVisibility}">
        <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}"
                                      DependentValuePath="Value"
                                      IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                      Name="Column">
            <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint}}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource myColor}"  Stroke="Black"/>
                                    <Grid Margin="0 -20 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}" Margin="2"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
        </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries>
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
            <Style TargetType="datavis:Legend">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:Chart">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Margin="3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />

                        <!-- Use a nested Grid to avoid possible clipping behavior resulting from ColumnSpan+Width=Auto -->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <datavis:Legend x:Name="Legend" Title="{TemplateBinding LegendTitle}" Style="{TemplateBinding LegendStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
                            <chartingprimitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
                                <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" />
                                <Border Canvas.ZIndex="10" BorderBrush="#FF919191" BorderThickness="1" />
                            </chartingprimitives:EdgePanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Template>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

в команде для очистки следующий код

```
DataSource = null;
```

Нужно сделать так, как на 1 рисунке

Comment: Используйте [`NullVisibilityConverter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21939778/6766879) и просто скрывайте график. Можете под ним даже разместить текст или картинку "нет данных"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил разместить `Label` на их месте и выводить уже его

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="ExpansesCalculation.ReportChart"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExpansesCalculation"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"  
    xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:datavis="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:chartingprimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Графики"
    Height="600" 
    Width="800"
    MinHeight="600"
    MinWidth="800"
    Background="#FFF0EAEA" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.25,0.5" Center="0,0" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" x:Key="myColor">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF3CC8DE" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FF3CAEDE" Offset="1.0" />
    </RadialGradientBrush>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <!--Rows and columns definition-->
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Chart column-->
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="12"
                           Margin="5"
                           Padding="0"
                           Name="chartColumn"
                           Visibility="{Binding ColumnSeriesVisibility}">
        <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}"
                                      DependentValuePath="Value"
                                      IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                      Name="Column">
            <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint}}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource myColor}"  Stroke="Black"/>
                                    <Grid Margin="0 -20 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}" Margin="2"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
        </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries>
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
            <Style TargetType="datavis:Legend">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:Chart">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Margin="3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />

                         <!--Use a nested Grid to avoid possible clipping behavior resulting from ColumnSpan+Width=Auto--> 
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <datavis:Legend x:Name="Legend" Title="{TemplateBinding LegendTitle}" Style="{TemplateBinding LegendStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
                            <chartingprimitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
                                <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" />
                                <Border Canvas.ZIndex="10" BorderBrush="#FF919191" BorderThickness="1" />
                            </chartingprimitives:EdgePanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Template>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>

    <!--Label-->
    <Label Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="12"
           Margin="5"
           Name="label"
           Content="{Binding LabelText}"
           FontSize="20"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Visibility="{Binding LabelVisibility}">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataSource.Count}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>

    <!--Chart Pie-->
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.RowSpan="1"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="12"
                           Margin="5"
                           Name="chartPie"
                           Padding="0"
                           Visibility="{Binding PieSeriesVisibility}">
        <chartingToolkit:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}"
                                   DependentValuePath="Value"
                                   IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                   Name="Pie"
                                   Padding="0">
            <!--<chartingToolkit:PieSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:PieDataPoint">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:PieDataPoint">
             Template here 
            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </chartingToolkit:PieSeries.DataPointStyle>-->
        </chartingToolkit:PieSeries>
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:Chart">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Margin="3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />

                         <!--Use a nested Grid to avoid possible clipping behavior resulting from ColumnSpan+Width=Auto--> 
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <datavis:Legend x:Name="Legend" Title="{TemplateBinding LegendTitle}" Style="{TemplateBinding LegendStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
                            <chartingprimitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
                                <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" />
                                <Border Canvas.ZIndex="10" BorderBrush="#FF919191" BorderThickness="1" />
                            </chartingprimitives:EdgePanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Template>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```